# A proof for the stationarity of an AR(2)

Tags: self-study, stationarity, arma

Consider a mean-centred AR(2) process $$X_t=\phi_1X_{t-1}+\phi_2X_{t-2}+\epsilon_t$$ where $\epsilon_t$ is the standard white noise process. Just for sake of simplicity let me call $\phi_1=b$ and $\phi_{2}=a$. Focusing on the roots of the characteristics equation I got $$z_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2a}$$
The classical conditions  in the textbooks are the following: $$\begin{cases}|a|<1 \\ a\pm b<1 \end{cases}$$
I tried to solve manually (with the help of Mathematica) the inequalities on the roots, i.e the system $$\begin{cases}|\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2a}|>1 \\ |\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2a}|>1\end{cases}$$ obtaining just $$a \pm b<1$$ Can the third condition ($|a|<1$) be recover adding the previous two solutions to each other getting $a+b+a-b<2 \Rightarrow a<1$ that through some sign considerations becomes $|a|<1$? Or am I missing a solution?

Comment: I have stuck in this question two days, thank you for your explanation. This is vary helpful!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

My guess is that the characteristic equation you are departing from is different from mine (based on discussion in Hamilton, Time Series Analysis). Let me proceed in a couple of steps to see whether we agree.

Consider the equation
$$
\lambda^2-\phi_1\lambda-\phi_2=0
$$

If $z$ is a root of the "standard" characteristic equation $1-\phi_1 z-\phi_2 z^2=0$ and setting $z^{-1}=\lambda$, the display obtains from rewriting the standard one as follows:
\begin{eqnarray*}
1-\phi_1 z-\phi_2 z^2&=&0\\
\Rightarrow z^{-2}-\phi_1 z^{-1}-\phi_2 &=&0\\
\Rightarrow \lambda^2-\phi_1\lambda -\phi_2 &=&0
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, an alternative condition for stability of an $AR(2)$ is that all roots of the first display are *inside* the unit circle, $|z|>1 \Leftrightarrow |\lambda|=|z^{-1}|<1$.

We use this representation to derive the *stationarity triangle* of an $AR(2)$ process, that is that an $AR(2)$ is stable if the following three conditions are met:

1. $\phi_2<1+\phi_1$
2. $\phi_2<1-\phi_1$
3. $\phi_2>-1$

Recall that you can write the roots of the first display (if real) as
$$
\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{\phi_1\pm\sqrt{\phi_1^2+4\phi_2}}{2}
$$
to find the first two conditions.

Then, the $AR(2)$ is stationary iff $|\lambda|<1$, hence (if the $\lambda_i$ are real):
\begin{eqnarray*}
-1<\frac{\phi_1\pm\sqrt{\phi_1^2+4\phi_2}}{2}&<&1\\
\Rightarrow    -2<\phi_1\pm\sqrt{\phi_1^2+4\phi_2}&<&2
\end{eqnarray*}
The larger of the two $\lambda_i$ is bounded by $\phi_1+\sqrt{\phi_1^2+4\phi_2}<2$,  or:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi_1+\sqrt{\phi_1^2+4\phi_2}&<&2\\
\Rightarrow \sqrt{\phi_1^2+4\phi_2}&<&2 - \phi_1\\
\Rightarrow \phi_1^2+4\phi_2&<&(2 - \phi_1)^2\\
\Rightarrow \phi_1^2+4\phi_2&<&4 - 4\phi_1+\phi_1^2\\
\Rightarrow \phi_2&<&1 - \phi_1
\end{eqnarray*}
Analogously, we find that $\phi_2<1 + \phi_1$.

If $\lambda_i$ is complex, then $\phi_1^2<-4\phi_2$ and so $$\lambda_{1,2} = \phi_1/2\pm i\sqrt{-(\phi_1^2+4\phi_2)}/2.$$ The squared modulus of a complex number is the square of the real plus the square of the imaginary part. Hence,
$$
\lambda^2 = (\phi_1/2)^2 + \left(\sqrt{-(\phi_1^2+4\phi_2)}/2\right)^2 = \phi_1^2/4-(\phi_1^2+4\phi_2)/4 = -\phi_2.
$$
This is stable if $|\lambda|<1$, hence if $-\phi_2<1$ or $\phi_2>-1$, as was to be shown. (The restriction $\phi_2<1$ resulting from $\phi_2^2<1$ is redundant in view of $\phi_2<1+\phi_1$ and $\phi_2<1-\phi_1$.)

Plotting the stationarity triangle, also indicating the line that separates complex from real roots, we get

[image]

Produced in R using

```
phi1 <- seq(from = -2.5, to = 2.5, length = 51) 
plot(phi1,1+phi1,lty="dashed",type="l",xlab="",ylab="",cex.axis=.8,ylim=c(-1.5,1.5))
abline(a = -1, b = 0, lty="dashed")
abline(a = 1, b = -1, lty="dashed")
title(ylab=expression(phi[2]),xlab=expression(phi[1]),cex.lab=.8)
polygon(x = phi1[6:46], y = 1-abs(phi1[6:46]), col="gray")
lines(phi1,-phi1^2/4)
text(0,-.5,expression(phi[2]<phi[1]^2/4),cex=.7)
text(1.2,.5,expression(phi[2]>1-phi[1]),cex=.7)
text(-1.75,.5,expression(phi[2]>1+phi[1]),cex=.7)
```

Comment: this is a very detailed explanation.

Comment: @Christoph: Is there a typo in the answer? Look at equation for $\lambda^2$. Also, what do you mean by square of a complex number? If $z = a + bi$ then $z^2 = a^2 - b^2 + 2iab$. How do you say square of a complex number is "square of the real plus the square of the imaginary part"

Comment: Thanks, quite right! I was referring to the sqaured modulus, see the edit.

Comment: @ChristophHanck, what is your take on Aksakal's answers in these two threads: [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/408880/what-is-the-meaning-of-an-autoregressive-parameter-greater-than-one/408886#408886) and [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/400781/explosive-arma-processes-are-stationary/400800#400800)? Are they in conflict with your answer, and if so, what is the correct answer?

Comment: I think he is quite right when defining weak stationarity as constancy of the first two moments. Often, and also in the present thread, "stationarity" and "existence of a causal representation", i.e., a summable $MA(\infty)$ representation without dependence on the future, are conflated. What my answer therefore more precisely shows is conditions for the existence of the latter.

Comment: @ChristophHanck I have one question. Can you explain to me why in this solution (and many others) we are ignoring other two inequalities, i.e. $\phi_1 - \sqrt{\phi_1^2 + 4\phi_2} < 2$ and $-2 < \phi_1 + \sqrt{\phi_1^2 + 4\phi_2}$? I was thinking that it has something to do with other two inequalities ($|\phi_1|<2$ and $|\phi_2|<1$) but my attempt failed.

Comment: The notation might be confusing, but I would read the inequalities as saying that the larger root must be less than two, and the smaller larger than minus two.