# Is this AR(2) model stationary?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, autoregressive

I have found an article about stationarity:
[Variance of a stationary AR(2) model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256437/variance-of-a-stationary-ar2-model)

and I have also estimated a model:

[image]

And I am not sure if I have understood it, is it truly stationary? And if so, could you show me how to derive it analytically?

Comment: Your estimates *assume* a stationary model.  What exactly do you wish to "derive analytically"??

Comment: @whuber What I mean is, I have heard that the AR coefficients cannot be equal nor bigger than 1, and as far as I know there are some exceptions from it. The problem is, I'm not sure how to prove it while having an actual example.

Comment: Check out [relevant posts about "unit roots" of AR processes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22unit+root%22+AR+polynomial).  For a fuller appreciation, one subtlety is treated at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/406204.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the process in companion form (as a VAR(1)):
$$\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
x_{n} \\ 
x_{n-1}%
\end{array}%
\right] =\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
2.84 \\ 
0%
\end{array}%
\right] +\left[ 
\begin{array}{cc}
1.36 & -0.75 \\ 
1 & 0%
\end{array}%
\right] \left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
x_{n-1} \\ 
x_{n-2}%
\end{array}%
\right] +\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
\varepsilon _{n} \\ 
0%
\end{array}%
\right] $$
The eigenvalues of the autoregression matrix are within the unit circle. Therefore, the process is stationary.

Comment: What is the autoregression matrix? The one with elements 1.36, -0.75, 1 and 0?