# Can autoregressive coefficient values be greater than 1?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, regression-coefficients, autoregressive

I am using multivariate autoregressive (MAR) models to fit my long-term dataset of species abundances and environmental variables but when I use only the data from a specific period of the year  (e.g., summer) instead of all of it, some coefficients from the resulting model are greater than 1. What does this mean? Should I reject these values from the final model? Why do I have this problem? Could it be caused by the small number of data? When I use all the data I don't have coefficients >1 or <-1.

Comment: Autoregressive parameters can be greater than 1 but sometimes there are constraints on the coefficients when stationarity is required or if the process should not be explosive.

Comment: Well yes, of course they can. This means the process is explosive. Whether the model makes any real world sense is a other question.

Comment: Maybe you need to apply a time-varying (TV) MVAR. In a TV MVAR the parameters of the model change with time implying that the interactions between time series are no longer constant.

Comment: Hi: the algorithms for the estimation of ARIMA models is fairly complex so, if there is no constraint in the alg for enforcing stationarity, you may get  AR coefficient estimates greater than but that doesn't mean that roots inside the unit circle wouldn't fit almost as well. I would try a regular arima algorithm from R ( there are many ) and see what happens there.

Comment: Oops. didn't see the multivariate aspect of your problem when I replied. There should be multivariate ARIMA algorithms in R but I don't know the package that has them. OTOH, If by multivariate, you just mean a VAR, then vars is the package you want to look at..

Comment: stationary AR(2) have coefficients greater than 1. For example, $y_t = 1.19 y_{t-1} - 0.23 y_{t-2} + e_t$ is stationary! You can check the region from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118019/a-proof-for-the-stationarity-of-an-ar2