# Stationarity for an AR(2) process

Tags: time-series, stationarity, autoregressive

How can I show that the following AR(2) process is stationary

$X_t = X_{t-1} + cX_{t-2}+Z_t$, provided -1 < c < 0 ?

I represented the series as $\Phi(B)X_t = Z_t$ and then tried to find out the roots of $\Phi(B)=0$ but couldn't figure out the solution.

Edit: The roots of $\Phi(B)=0$ are $\cfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4c}}{2c}$

Comment: Do you know that this process is stationary and want to prove it or are you asking if it is stationary and why? To me, it's not obvious why this is stationary. The term $X_{t−1}$ adds complexity...

Comment: Well, under the condition -1<c<0, we need to show it is stationary. Or, assuming the process to be stationary, we need to show that -1<c<0.

Comment: Thanks for that, I would have never guessed this was stationary by just looking at the terms :)

Comment: What are the roots of $\Phi(B)$?

Comment: I have updated the question to mention roots of $\Phi(B)=0$.

Comment: A general solution can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118019/a-proof-for-the-stationarity-of-an-ar2/145652#145652). For your case, just put $\phi_1=1$ and $\phi_2=c$.