# Is it possible to describe a AR(1) process as stable in terms of a stability triangle?

Tags: time-series, arima, autoregressive, unit-root

Is it possible to describe AR(1) as stable in terms of a unit triangle as in the explanation below or not because a lack of a second degree characteristic polynomial?

> Consider the equation $$ \lambda^2-\phi_1\lambda-\phi_2=0 $$
>
> If $z$ is a root of the "standard" characteristic equation $1-\phi_1
> > z-\phi_2 z^2=0$ and setting $z^{-1}=\lambda$, the display obtains from
> rewriting the standard one as follows: \begin{eqnarray*} 1-\phi_1
> > z-\phi_2 z^2&=&0\\ \Rightarrow z^{-2}-\phi_1 z^{-1}-\phi_2 &=&0\\
> > \Rightarrow \lambda^2-\phi_1\lambda -\phi_2 &=&0 \end{eqnarray*}
> Hence, an alternative condition for stability of an $AR(2)$ is that
> all roots of the first display are *inside* the unit circle, $|z|>1
> > \Leftrightarrow |\lambda|=|z^{-1}|<1$.
>
> We use this representation to derive the *stationarity triangle* of an
> $AR(2)$ process, that is that an $AR(2)$ is stable if the following
> three conditions are met:
>
> 1. $\phi_2<1+\phi_1$
> 2. $\phi_2<1-\phi_1$
> 3. $\phi_2>-1$
>
> Recall that you can write the roots of the first display (if real) as
> $$
> >     \lambda_{1,2}=\frac{\phi_1\pm\sqrt{\phi_1^2+4\phi_2}}{2}
> >     $$
> to find the first two conditions.
>
> Then, the $AR(2)$ is stationary iff $|\lambda|<1$, hence (if the
> $\lambda_i$ are real):
> \begin{eqnarray*}
> >     -1<\frac{\phi_1\pm\sqrt{\phi_1^2+4\phi_2}}{2}&<&1\\ \Rightarrow    -2<\phi_1\pm\sqrt{\phi_1^2+4\phi_2}&<&2
> >     \end{eqnarray*} The larger of the two $\lambda_i$ is bounded by $\phi_1+\sqrt{\phi_1^2+4\phi_2}<2$,  or: \begin{eqnarray*}
> > \phi_1+\sqrt{\phi_1^2+4\phi_2}&<&2\\ \Rightarrow
> > \sqrt{\phi_1^2+4\phi_2}&<&2 - \phi_1\\ \Rightarrow
> > \phi_1^2+4\phi_2&<&(2 - \phi_1)^2\\ \Rightarrow \phi_1^2+4\phi_2&<&4 -
> > 4\phi_1+\phi_1^2\\ \Rightarrow \phi_2&<&1 - \phi_1 \end{eqnarray*}
> Analogously, we find that $\phi_2<1 + \phi_1$.
>
> If $\lambda_i$ is complex, then $\phi_1^2<-4\phi_2$ and so
> $$\lambda_{1,2} = \phi_1/2\pm i\sqrt{-(\phi_1^2+4\phi_2)}/2.$$ The
> squared modulus of a complex number is the square of the real plus the
> square of the imaginary part. Hence,  $$ \lambda^2 = (\phi_1/2)^2 +
> > \left(\sqrt{-(\phi_1^2+4\phi_2)}/2\right)^2 =
> > \phi_1^2/4-(\phi_1^2+4\phi_2)/4 = -\phi_2. $$  This is stable if
> $|\lambda|<1$, hence if $-\phi_2<1$ or $\phi_2>-1$, as was to be
> shown. (The restriction $\phi_2<1$ resulting from $\phi_2^2<1$ is
> redundant in view of $\phi_2<1+\phi_1$ and $\phi_2<1-\phi_1$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second condition fails.

If you have an non-stable AR1 process then $\phi_1 = 1$. You could interpret it, if you like, as a AR2 process with $\phi_2 = 0$. Then you have that the second condition fails

$$0=\phi_2<1-\phi_1 = 0$$

The condition $0<0$ is false.

---

The characteristic equation of higher order but with coefficients zero will have the same roots but with some additional roots equal to zero. $\lambda^2-\lambda \theta_1- \theta_2$ and $\lambda-\theta_1$ are just the same when $\theta_2=0$ (except for that additional root $\lambda = 0$).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, since there is only one coefficient, there is no two-dimensional figure to plot (unlike the answer [A proof for the stationarity of an AR(2)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118019/a-proof-for-the-stationarity-of-an-ar2/145652#145652) you cite, which discusses the AR(2) case). Stability means that all solutions to the characteristic polynomial are outside the unit circle.

In this case, the polynomial is just $1-\phi z=0$, such that the condition becomes
$$
|z|>1/|\phi|
$$
or $|\phi|<1$.