# Time series - stability

Tags: time-series

I'm studying time series from the Hamilton's book.

I have the following question:

Consider a 2nd order difference equation:

$y_t=\phi_1 y_{t-1}+\phi_2 y_{t-2}+w_t$

By using the lag-operator, I write: $(1-\phi_1L-\phi_2L^2)y_t=w_t$

I can factorize my polynomial in the lag operator as

$(1-\phi_1 L -\phi_2 L^2)=(1-\lambda_1 L)(1- \lambda_2 L)=[1- (\lambda_1+\lambda_2)L+(\lambda_1 \lambda_2)L^2]$ $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ [1]$

with: $\lambda_1 +\lambda_2=\phi_1$, and $\lambda_1 \lambda_2=-\phi_2$

I want to find the values for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ such that the left hand side of $[1]$ is equal to the right hand side.

Then, the book says to replace the values of $L$, with a scalar $z$ as follows

$(1-\phi_1 z -\phi_2 z^2)=(1-\lambda_1 z)(1- \lambda_2 z) $ $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ [2]$

Then the values making the right hand side of $[2]$ equal to zero are $z=\lambda_1^{-1}$ or $z=\lambda_2^{-1}$.

The question is why the right hand side of $[2]$ should be zero? Is that because $(1-\phi_1 z -\phi_2 z^2)=0$ is the characteristic equation of the my polynomial in the lag operator and by construction it is zero? Indeed, $z$ should be the roots of the characteristic equation. Am I right?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118019/a-proof-for-the-stationarity-of-an-ar2

Comment: The mathematical steps are clear, but it seems that I'm right, $(1−\phi_1 z−\phi_2 z^2)=0
 $ is the characteristic equation. That's why the RHS of $[2]$ must be zero